# "года" или "годы"?

Tags: число, грамматика

> Несмотря на юные **года** / **годы**.

Как правильно? Я слышал как телеведущий сказал **года**. Но согласно сайту [morpher.ru](http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx), множественное число будет **годы**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) ИЗ ГРАММАТИКИ-80

возможны оба варианта: *годы и года*, но только: *двадцатые годы и годы юности* (о названном историческом периоде).

2) ЧАСТОТНОСТЬ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ

Если сравнить частотность употребления года/годы на примере сочетания "эти годы", то соотношение (указанное в Нацкорпусе) будет 46:2 844, тогда  форму "годы" можно считать основной.

3) РАЗНАЯ СЕМАНТИКА?

Сравним  использование формы "эти годы/года" в произведениях классиков:

ЭТИ ГОДЫ: Пришёл отец, Егор Егорович, тоже сдавший за эти годы (А. Н. Толстой). Вот чего ему не хватало все эти годы, бедному мальчику, думала она (В. Аксенов).

ЭТИ ГОДА: Это были слезы радости пробуждения в себе того духовного существа, которое все эти года спало в нем (Л. Н. Толстой). Гляди, как рухнулось все за эти года! (М. А. Шолохов).  Мне сорок лет, и в эти года показаться смешным ― смерть… (Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк).

Мне кажется, можно сделать следующие выводы. **Раньше форма "года" применялась чаще и мало отличалась от формы "годы". Впоследствии наметилось смысловое различие этих форм.**

Года - это период жизни с определенной качественной характеристикой (юные года, в такие года). Годы - это просто относительный период времени (восьмидесятые годы, прошедшие годы)

Answer (score 4):

Сто лет назад В.И. Чернышев ("Правильность и чистота русской речи") "годы" относил к старым формам, "года" -- к новым, и на вопрос, каких форм следовало бы держаться в употреблении, отвечал так:

*"Мы видим вообще поступательное движение и победу новых форм с **а, я** над формами с **ы, и,** и это даёт нам основание смело держаться новых форм, если мы усвоили их употребление. Ведь и формы **века, дома, края, паруса, писаря, пояса, учителя, рога, снега** лет сто тому назад должны были казаться вульгарными, малограмотными".*

Долгое время после этого "года" и "годы" считались словарями равноправными, но…
Не знаю почему, но недавно вышедший "Большой орфоэпический словарь" (Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф. "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты", М., 2012) нормативности у формы "года" немного поубавил. В нём так:

**ГОД**, мн. **ГОДЫ** и допуст. мн. **ГОДА**.

Может, именно на этот словарь и ориентировались авторы morpher.ru.

Answer (score 1):

Сайт, конечно, интересный...

Но его никак нельзя признать нормативным.
Все словари дают формы *г**о**ды* и *год**а*** как равноправные.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E3%EE%E4&all=x

Лично я подозреваю, что более новая форма *года* чаще используется в возвышенной, патетической речи и года на это слово падает смысловое ударение. В то время как годы - в обычном, эмоционально не окрашенном контексте.

Но это, повторюсь, мое мнение. Нормативно, согласно словарям, обе формы равноправны и не несут каких-либо отличительных признаков.